# Batch File: How to delete specific files in folder selected by interval

Tags: batch-file

I want to know how to go about this, here is what I want to do.

My Batch file will delete every **nth** file of the folder it is in. 
I know how the file should run but I don't know the line of code to write.

The idea is:

- 1st ask for the interval variable
- 2nd delete every file within the interval
- 3rd End

For example, in 100 files sorted. And I enter interval 5. 
Every 5th file should remain. So only 20 files should be left after running the batch file. Other files should be deleted.

This is how far I have gone only

```
@echo off
title ImageDeleter
echo Delete every _ files?
set /p interval=
FOR /D %%interval IN (folder_set) DO del filename
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

1) First thing first, looks like you don't know much about `for` loop in batch programming. The `%%interval` is a big mistake, no one use assigned variable as `for` loop's variable, you should use `%%a` or `%%b` or whatever instead. Google for loop in batch for more information.
2) To sort alphabetically for file names, use `dir /o:n` where `n` indicates what you want to sort by (names).
3) Deleted files won't go to **recycle bin**, meaning you can't restore back (else you have a file recovery software), so think again before you want to delete them.
4) Learn more before you ask a question on stackoverflow, and don't leave an undone code for us to fill up, we basically won't help you to do that. 
If any changes in **path**, change it inside the code. If you want your code to get the path automatically by entering the path during execution, LEARN MORE :)

```
@echo off
title ImageDeleter
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:main
cls
set /p interval=Interval=
set /a skip=5
set /a count_skip=0
set /a count=1
set /a number=1

cd c:\users\microsoft\desktop\del

for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('dir /o:n c:\users\microsoft\desktop\del\') do (
    if !count_skip! equ !skip! (
        set /a count_skip-=1
        if %%a equ free (
            echo.
            echo Finished!
            pause >nul
            exit /b
        )
        if !count! neq !interval! (
            echo !number!. DELETED - %%a
            del %%a
        )
        if !count! equ !interval! (
            echo.
            echo !number!. REMAINED - %%a
            echo.
            set /a count=0
        )
        set /a count+=1
        set /a number+=1
    )
    set /a count_skip+=1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the topic title you said: "delete specific files". Then, you wrote: "will delete every nth file" (for example, if N=5 delete files 5, 10 15, etc.), but later you said: "I enter interval 5. Every 5th file should remain" (so files 1,2,3,4 6,7,8,9 11,12,13,14 etc. must be deleted). ???

The first code below delete every nth file, so it will delete 20 files from 100 and keep 80:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

title ImageDeleter
echo Delete every _ files?
set /p n=
set i=0
FOR %%a IN (file_set) DO (
   set /A i+=1, iMODn=i %% n
   if !iMODn! equ 0 del "%%a"
)
```

The next code *keep* every nth file and delete the rest, so it will delete 80 files from 100 and keep 20:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

title ImageDeleter
echo Delete every _ files?
set /p n=
set i=0
FOR %%a IN (file_set) DO (
   set /A i+=1, iMODn=i %% n
   if !iMODn! neq 0 del "%%a"
)
```